# Convert Python's binascii.crc_hqx() back to ascii

Tags: python, crc, crc16, binascii

I'm using the standard Python3 lib [`binascii`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/binascii.html), and specifically the [`crc_hqx()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/binascii.html#binascii.crc_hqx) function

> **binascii.crc_hqx(data, value)**
>
> Compute a 16-bit CRC value of data, starting with value as the initial CRC, and return the result. This uses the CRC-CCITT polynomial x16 + x12 + x5 + 1, often represented as 0x1021. This CRC is used in the binhex4 format.

I'm able to convert to CRC with this code:

```
import binascii
t = 'abcd'
z = binascii.crc_hqx(t.encode('ascii'), 0)
print(t,z)
```

which, as expected, prints the line

```
abcd 43062
```

**But how do I convert back to ASCII?**

I've tried variations with the [`a2b_hqx()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/binascii.html#binascii.a2b_hqx) function

> **binascii.a2b_hqx(string)**
>
> Convert binhex4 formatted ASCII data to binary, without doing RLE-decompression. The string should contain a complete number of binary bytes, or (in case of the last portion of the binhex4 data) have the remaining bits zero.

The simplest version would be:

```
y = binascii.a2b_hqx(str(z))
```

But I've also tried variations with [`bytearray()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray) and [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode), etc.

---

For this code:

```
import binascii
t = 'abcd'
z = binascii.crc_hqx(t.encode('ascii'), 0)
print(t,z)
y = binascii.a2b_hqx(str(z))
```

the Traceback:

```
abcd 43062
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    y = binascii.a2b_hqx(str(z))
binascii.Incomplete: String has incomplete number of bytes
```

And with this code:

```
y = binascii.a2b_hqx(bytearray(z))
```

This Traceback:

```
binascii.Error: Illegal char
```

Comment: I'm starting to think that it's a checksum and not possible to convert back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is generated is a checksum and not possible to convert back to ascii.